# Retain the mouse over element onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This might look simple but unfortunately I am not getting how to get this effect.

I have a div which has a child div inside which needs to be displayed on `mouse-over` of parent div.

The child div has another content panel in it which has to be displayed on click of child div.

These 2 works well but the problem here is, I need to show the child div on mouse leave only if child is clicked.

```
$(".wrapper").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).find('.child').show();
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).find('.child').hide();
});


$(".child").click(function() {
        $(this).find('span').show();

});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/yapeveku/2/)**

Comment: Did you mean ' I need to **hide** the child div on mouse leave' ?

Comment: No. it is hiding it on mouse leave but i want to show it even on mouse leave only when the child is cliked

Comment: @Sowmya: Means you want if the child is clicked then the div not hide on mouse leave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would help you.

Try this:

```
  $(".wrapper").mouseover(function() {
            $(this).find('.child').show();
        }).mouseleave(function(){
            if($(this).find('.child span').is(':visible') == false){
                $(this).find('.child').hide();
            }
    });


    $(".child").click(function() {
        $(this).find('span').show();        
    });
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uGvs2/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a class on the parent while clicking, check whether it has that class on mouse leave:

```
$(".wrapper").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find('.child').show();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('clicked'))
      $(this).find('.child').hide();
});

$(".child").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('clicked').find('.child span').show();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gtWcb/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var clicked=false;
$(".wrapper").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find('.child').show();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    if(!clicked){
        $(this).find('.child').hide();
        }
});

$(".child").click(function() {
    $(this).find('span').show();
    clicked=true;
});
```